# Open ACCESS Application thru C# Application on windows 7

Tags: c#, ms-access, desktop-application

Some background:
we have a windows application (c#) that locate in the system try.
that simple application is a basically shortcuts manger for other application and messaging between the workers.

one of the application is an Access 2007 application (connected to sqlserver) - the client works with ACCESS Runtime 2007 (latest version)

THE problem is that we can not launch the Access application correctly from the C# application.
THE problem is only on windows 7 (we don't have vista) - [on XP OS everything works fine)

"correctly"  - meaning that the Access application running but the Ribbon Bar is missing some Icons (strange). also some functionality like open the Outlook is not working.

Some more Info:
- IF we put shortcut on the client desktop to the Access application everything ok.
- The C# application have no problem to launch other EXE file. 

- The C# application include Manifest file (run as admin on Win 7).

---

The Original code is very simple (Works only in  XP):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(AppPath);
```

The 'Open EXE' code that works (Works on XP and Win7)-[not working with Access Application]

```
Process Proc= new Process();
Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\PasswordManager.exe";
Proc.Start();
```

We try many codes with no success like [NOT WORKING]:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = sAccPath;// msaccess Path;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"""" + AppPath+ @""""; 
proc.Start();
```

We also try to add [NOT WORKING]:

```
System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
if (osInfo.Version.Major > 5) 
        proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Helppppppppppp!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We uninstall current OFFICE SBE 2007 and Install a newest version of OFFICE SBE 2007.
everything works fine now.
our conclusion is that Office SBE 2007 first version (instaled at client computer) doesn't work well with Access Runtime 2007.

(weird, but work)

David, Thank You very much.

Comment: As I said, I think the SBE includes the runtime, so maybe the old version of SBE was reverting the runtime to an old version, or otherwise somehow corrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong on this, but my guess is that it's running in reduced functionality mode due to your not defining a trusted location from which it can run. I don't know how this is done in code, but if you launch A2007, it's on the Office menu under Access Options (I'm posting from menu, as I mostly use A2003 and don't want to wait through the re-registration process).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this is not the case.
As I mention, if we run the application from a desktop shortcut - everything works well. 
We also try do add manually the Trusted Locations into the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations.
with no help. 

Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched the Access newsgroups for this issue on Google Groups? It really does sound a lot like the reduced-functionality mode that you get when your "macro security" levels and trusted locations are not properly set up.

Comment: yes I know it's sound (and act) like this but everything works well if i'm not using the C# application to launce the ms-access apllication. so, I think it's more a C# problem then Access problem. I think that the way we are trying run the Access application (from the C# application) is wrong and causes the ms-access to work in reduced-functionality mode.-- TA.

Comment: We found Somthing interesting- On the client computer if an Office 2007 business Edition is install with Access runtime 2007 then we still have the problem. but if we install office 2000 with Access Runtime 2007 it works well. ?!?!

Comment: That sounds like you're getting different versions of the A2007 runtime (I don't know this for a fact but the Small Business Edition used to install the Access runtime as part of its full/default installation). What happens if you re-install a freshly downloaded A2007 runtime on the machine with Office 2007 SBE?

Comment: We do install The updated Access 2007 Runtime. 
We even Formart the Comuter and before we install The SBE everything work fine with only A2007 runtime, the problem return when we install the SBE. (weird), if we upgrade the SBE to standard Edition with MS Access, again everything work fine. mayby somthing with our SBE version ?

Comment: Maybe the SBE is overwriting the updated runtime? Perhaps you need a more up-to-date version of SBE. For what it's worth, I avoid SBE because it has historically been a very problematic Office version.